# How to prevent the text of an anchor element from breaking if it's multiple words, instead shift it to the next line

Tags: html, css

I have a div and inside it, I have links to categories.  In mobile view, the links to the categories break up if it has spaces or more than a word.

[image]

In this example, if I have "Test" and whatever number together instead of a space, it would work just fine, however, with the spaces, you get the numbers in another line.  How do I make this work so that it shifts the entire link to another line so that it doesn't break it?  Using white-space and any of its values doesn't really work in this situation since the spaces in the categories are what breaks it.

If possible, I'd like to keep this purely CSS and HTML if possible, unless there's no other way around this.

```css
.postedIn {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto p-md-5 fullPost mb-5">
  <div class="row mt-5 pt-5" id="postCategoryTagContainer" style="width: 280px">
    <div class="col-8 mt-3 postedIn">
        <span id="postedIn">Posted in:</span>&nbsp;<?php the_category('&nbsp;') ?>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-1" rel="category    tag">Test 1</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-2" rel="category tag">Test 2</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-4" rel="category tag">Test 4</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-5" rel="category tag">Test 5</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test3" rel="category tag">Test 3</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/uncategorized" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pick where to allow wrapping. You use `&nbsp;`, but not in `Posted in:` or "the spaced category designations" (tags?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to add is `white-space: nowrap` to all child elements of `.postedIn`-element to prevent a line-break within a white-space.

`.postedIn > * { white-space: nowrap; }` will solve the issue already without further changes such as adding flexbox.

```css
.postedIn {
  width: 100%;
}

.postedIn > * {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto p-md-5 fullPost mb-5">
  <div class="row mt-5 pt-5" id="postCategoryTagContainer" style="width: 280px">
    <div class="col-8 mt-3 postedIn">
        <span id="postedIn">Posted in:</span>&nbsp;<?php the_category('&nbsp;') ?>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-1" rel="category    tag">Test 1</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-2" rel="category tag">Test 2</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-4" rel="category tag">Test 4</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-5" rel="category tag">Test 5</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test3" rel="category tag">Test 3</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/uncategorized" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i can propose you a full css solution.

all your container element can play with

```
 white-space: nowrap
```

to don't have break line

```css
 .postedIn {
    white-space: nowrap
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto p-md-5 fullPost mb-5">
  <div class="row mt-5 pt-5" id="postCategoryTagContainer" style="width: 280px">
    <div class="col-8 mt-3 postedIn">
        <span id="postedIn">Posted in:</span>&nbsp;<?php the_category('&nbsp;') ?>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-1" rel="category    tag">Test 1</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-2" rel="category tag">Test 2</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-4" rel="category tag">Test 4</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-5" rel="category tag">Test 5</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test3" rel="category tag">Test 3</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/uncategorized" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need flexbox at all. `white-space: nowrap` will solve the issue on its own even if the elements reamain to be `inline`-elements.

Comment: yes thank you only white-space: nowrap on container is needed.

i edit my reply to only let this part

Comment: actually you need to add this to the child elements of the container. Currently you overflow the set width of 280px.

Comment: Thanks, however, the problem with that is that it overflows the width of the div.  I needed it to shift to a new line if it can't fit within the div next to another category link.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is running into this issue specifically developing a theme for WordPress, the answer Tacoshy gave works, however, for some reason once inside a WordPress theme it may or may not work, depending on your code.  If it doesn't work, in my case it was display: inline-block to the span with the ID "postedIn" or display: contents to the parent div with the class "postedIn" that fixes it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
There is a solution in css, 

.postedIn {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto p-md-5 fullPost mb-5">
  <div class="row mt-5 pt-5" id="postCategoryTagContainer" style="width: 280px">
    <div class="col-8 mt-3 postedIn">
        <span id="postedIn">Posted in:</span>&nbsp;<?php the_category('&nbsp;') ?>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-1" rel="category    tag">Test 1</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-2" rel="category tag">Test 2</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-4" rel="category tag">Test 4</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test-5" rel="category tag">Test 5</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/test3" rel="category tag">Test 3</a>
        &nbsp;<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/archives/category/uncategorized" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how does this solve the issue? If he wanted to just have all the tags belwo each other he would just need to use `display: block`. No need for flexbox. The issue is not the alignment but the line-break within the tag.

Comment: But they mentioned like want to display each anchor tag (entire link ) to another line. That's why I added the css as display: flex;

Comment: he mentioned that he want to move the entire link to a next-line instead of breaking the link so that it remain in 2 lines. He not asked to place all links below each other.